# Проверка на дубликат

Tags: vue.js

Как проверить если значения с v-model="task" равно элементу в массиве this.todos - тогда мы не будем пушать его в массив todos
(Проверка на дубликат в массив)

Я так питался сделать

```
 eventTodoAdd() {
  for (let i=0; i<this.todos.length; i++) {
    this.task === this.todos[i] ? !this.todos.push(this.task) : this.todos.push(this.task)
  }
  console.log('ДОДАНО')
  this.task = ''
}
```

Comment: eventTodoAdd() {
      this.todos.push(this.task)

      let el = this.todos.find(item => item===this.task)
      if (this.task === el) {
        console.log('Have dublicates')
      }
      this.task = ''

    }

Comment: ну или так - но не заработало )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так, точно работает:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="" v-model="task" @change="eventTodoAdd">
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
name: "Test",
  data() {
    return {
    task: null,
      todos: ['1','2','3','4', '5'],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    eventTodoAdd(){
      let isUniq = true;
        this.todos.forEach(item => {     
         item === this.task ? isUniq=false : null
        })
      isUniq ? this.todos.push(this.task) : null
      console.log(this.todos)
    },
  },

}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```